# Запись в определенную строку файла на Python

Tags: python

Появилась необходимость записывать данные в определенную строку в большом файле на пару гигов. Конкретнее, сейчас нужно считывать строку, далее ее обрабатывать, и потом удалять с текстового файла.

Нашел решение, состоящее в том что бы считать весь файл в переменную, потом внести изменения в переменную и по новому всё записать, но для большого объема данных это, очевидно, не лучший вариант.

Может быть это решить можно попроще? Если нет, то собственно сам вопрос, как записать данные в определенную строку без перезаписи всего файла?

Comment: весь файл переписывать не обязательно, но от места удаления и до конца файл придется переписать.

Comment: Может имеет смысл использовать другой формат (не текстовый), или даже базу данных?

Comment: "Конкретнее, сейчас нужно считывать строку, далее ее обрабатывать, и потом удалять с текстового файла." Т.е. ее не перезаписывать надо а удалять?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Файл - это просто последовательность байтов, среди которых встречаются переносы строк. Т.е. если вы работаете с файлом:

```
строка 1
строчка 2
строка 3
```

...то на самом деле на диске лежит последовательность байтов:

```
строка 1␊строчка 2␊строка 3
```

---

Вы можете [перезаписать некоторые байты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509014/1026), не пересчитывая/перезаписывая весь файл, как внутри строки, так и между строк, например:

```
строка 1␊XXXXXXXXXXXтрока 3
```

тогда, просматривая файл по строкам, вы увидите:

```
строка 1
XXXXXXXXXXXтрока 3
```

...но никак нельзя удалить кусок из середины файла, ничего не делая с той частью, которая идет после удаляемого куска.

---

Вы можете построить код таким образом, чтобы [читать из файла строки по одной и писать их сразу же в файл на новое место](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329972/1026), например, если удаляем строку 1:

1. читаем "строка 1", пропускаем:

   ```
             ↓ позиция для чтения
    строка 1␊строчка 2␊строка 3
    ↑ позиция для записи
   ```
2. читаем "строчка 2":

   ```
                       ↓ позиция для чтения
    строка 1␊строчка 2␊строка 3
    ↑ позиция для записи
   ```
3. Записываем "строчка 2" на новое место:

   ```
                       ↓ позиция для чтения
    строчка 2␊трочка 2␊строка 3
              ↑ позиция для записи
   ```
4. Аналогично, читаем "строка 3" и пишем ее на новое место:

   ```
                               ↓ позиция для чтения
    строчка 2␊строка 3␊строка 3
                       ↑ позиция для записи
   ```
5. Обрезаем ненужное место в конце файла:

   ```
    строчка 2␊строка 3␊
   ```

Если вы хотите не удалять строку, а вместо одной строки писать другую, то надо быть внимательным в случае если новая строка длиннее старой. На этот случай примера кода у меня нет.

---

Как видно, плоские файлы - неудачный способ хранения большого объема данных, если нужно что-то менять "посередине". Если вы сами создаете этот файл, возможно стоит рассмотреть другие форматы хранения, более эффективные для нужных вам операций.

Answer (score 3):

Для относительно небольших файлов, [`fileinput` может работать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20593644/4279), чтобы удалить строки из файла, удовлетворяющие заданному условию:

```
import fileinput
import os

def remove_lines(filename, condition):
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
        for line in file:
            if not condition(line):
                print(line, end='') # keep line
    os.unlink(filename + '.bak') # remove backup on success
```

Вместо удаления строки, можно её комментировать, например, записывая `#` в начало строки -- это не меняет кол-во байт, поэтому не требует переписывания всего последующего содержимого. [`mmap` работает даже для больших файлов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522826/4279).

Для быстрой работы с большим кол-вом данных, плоский текстовый файл плохо подходит. Вместо изобретения своего фиксированного бинарного формата, следует использовать уже существующие базы данных такие как SQLite, PostgreSQL, MongoDB итд. в зависимости, что больше подходит под конкретную задачу.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать свой "велосипед" с бинарным файлом, "раскладка" данных примерно такая:

1. Сначала идут текстовые строки, разделенные нулевыми байтами
2. Дальше таблица смещений ("указателей") всех строк от начала файла. Эта таблица позволит:

   - Добавлять строку физически в конец блока строк, но в таблице строк вставлять ее смещение сразу в нужно место, хоть в середину. Это избавит от необходимости физически перемещать кучу строк, находящихся после вставленной строки. При вставке сдвигается относительно небольшой блок данных - только таблица строк.
   - Не удалять строку физически, а например убирать ее смещение из общей таблицы и добавлять в таблицу удаленных строк (опционально)
   - Для того, чтобы поменять местами две строки, достаточно будет поменять местами их смещения в таблице строк.
3. Опциональная таблица удаленных строк. Собственно, хранит смещения удаленных строк, чтобы при необходимости делать одну общую операцию "сборки мусора" на весь файл. Возможна реализация сборки мусора и без этой таблицы.
4. Ну и в самый конец записываем размеры таблицы строк и таблицы удаленных строк.

Польза от этого:

1. Как уже говорилось, не нужно физически сдвигать строки, чтобы вставить одну строку в середину. Перезаписать таблицу строк проще, т.к. она явно значительно меньше по размеру.
2. Чтобы добраться до N-ной строки не читать N-1 предыдущих строк - достаточно обратиться к N-ному элементу в таблице строк.
3. "Отложенное" удаление - можно удалить строку из таблицы строк, но сдвигать строки только когда в этом будет реальная необходимость (например, если файл разрастется раза в полтора - условно, строки занимают 4 Гб, а файл без учета таблиц строк занимает 6 Гб).
4. Для работы со одной строкой не нужно считывать весь файл (как например при использовании json)

А вообще, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды, стоит посмотреть в сторону какой-нибудь базы данных.

---

**Другой вариант**, если вам нужно только удалять обработанные строки, а новые добавлять только в конец, то можно сделать вот так: мы не меняем формат хранения данных, а строим таблицу смещений всех строк, и сохраняем ее в отдельный файл. Дальше, по мере обработки файла, мы просто удаляем смещения обработанных строк из таблицы смещений. При добавлении строк в конец исходного файла мы можем также добавлять их смещения в таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

> Появилась необходимость записывать данные в определенную строку в большом файле на пару гигов. Конкретнее, сейчас нужно считывать строку, далее ее обрабатывать, и потом удалять с текстового файла.

Можно взять redis для хранения соответсвий `<номер строки>: <имя файла>` и каждую строку хранить в одтельном файле. Либо хранить прямо в redis, если его он позволяет хранить необходимое количество данных.

Для хранение соответсвий можно использвать структуру [sorted set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets).

Можно еще сделать свою версию нужного функционала для хранения соответствий с redis, с помощью словаря, который, к примеру, сериализировать в json и сбрасывать на диск при остановке программы, чтобы не тратить время на восстановление этих данных при запуске.