# Указатель на начало любой строки

Tags: python

Пишу программу для работы с текстовыми файлами. Столкнулся с проблемой:
В файле я нахожу строки, которые содержат ключевые слова, символы. Типа `[H009]`, `[A008]`, `Name=` и т.д.
Но дело в том, что мне нужно записать новую строку сразу после найденного слова, пока что не могу догадаться как реализовать поиск нужного кол-ва байтов на переход указателя `seek(x)`.

Comment: метод `seek` для _текстовых_ файлов переходит не на количество байт, а на количество символов. Для бинарных файлов можно использовать `tell`, который скажет, где сейчас указатель (в байтах).

Comment: Хорошо, но в любом случае как это сделать? Как я понял, Python не позволяет нативным образом переместить указатель на начало нужной строки(?).

Comment: Любой язык не позволит прыгать по строкам. До того, как файл прочитан расположение спец-символов окончания строки неизвестно. Соответственно, нужно хоть разок файл полностью прочитать. Можно, например, составить словарь, в котором ключем будет номер строки, а значением смещение первого символа этой строки относительно нуля (начала файла).

Comment: @m9_psy 1- для текстовых файлов file.tell() возвращает непрозрачное значение (не обязательно количество символов) 2- если у вас есть аргумент для file.seek() метода (значение file.tell() в прошлом), то можно это "указателем" рассматривать (слово "указатель" лучше не использовать так как конфликтует с этим понятием в С. Можно cookie или position переменную обозвать). 3- если длина нового слова в байтах не равна старому, то затрётся содержимое (придётся до самого конца переписывать файл).

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Запись в определенную строку файла на Python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/445953/23044)

Answer (score -1):

Если файл небольшого размера, то можно поступить проcто и воспользоваться методом `readlines()`. Если держать файл в памяти целиком желания нет, то

для того, чтобы иметь возможность переходить на начало любой произвольной строки в файле, его необходимо полностью прочитать и составить специальный индекс. Индекс будет представлять из себя массив, где номер элемента - это номер строки в файле, а сам элемент - это смещение первого символа в этой строке. Единственное, что вас может подстерегать на этом пути, так это то, что на Windows могут обрезаться `/r/n` символы:

```
lines_index = []

with open("test_file", 'r', buffering=1, encoding="utf8") as file:
    while file.readline():
        lines_index.append(file.tell())

    file.seek(lines_index[5])
    print(file.readline())  # Прочитать шестую строку
```

Решение с `while file.readline()` кроссплатформенное (в отличие от `for line in file`).

Также стоит отметить, что `file.tell()` возвращает "непрозрачное значение" ([`io.TextIOBase.tell`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell), [Methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)), которое можно использовать в методе `seek`, а не количество прочитанных символов.