# Как перезаписать ОПРЕДЕЛЕННУЮ строку в txt файле при помощи python?

Tags: python, запись, txt

Как перезаписать ОПРЕДЕЛЕННУЮ строку в txt файле так, что бы указать какая строка будет перезаписана и что будет перезаписано(например, я хочу что бы первая строка была изменена на слово "привет". Так же очень важно, что бы не имело значения, что уже написано на этой строке.)

Заранее спасибо :З

Comment: собственные поиски дали какой результат?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запись в определенную строку файла на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445953/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Comment: @timur, ну зачем вы так грубо? Это же новый участник, специально написано